# Implications of JS inheritance with prototype _.extend

Tags: underscore.js, prototypal-inheritance

A friend of mine asked me why would you do a proper prototype inheritance if you could just use underscore extend function?

```
_.extend(A.prototype, B.prototype)
```

Are there any negative implications of this approach?

Comment: Prototype chain is not established. It simply copies the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If You want create object by `prototype`, You can use only `object` for this:

```js
function A(){
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
};

var B = {
    b : 'b',
    c : 'c'
};

_.extend(A.prototype, B);
var a = new A;
```

In this case `_.extend` would be working as You (or Your friend =) ) expected: object `a` has propertirs `a` & `b`:
[image: a - underscore]

But in prototype chains, object `a` has propertie `c`:
[image: a.c - underscore]

But why use `underscore`, when JS has a standard feature for this?

Comment: What is js standard feature?

Comment: @FreeLightman Sorry. Me from past knew answer to this question, but Me from present, long time don't work with prototyping, and I really don't remember what I meant 2 years ago =\ (shame on me)